# Binary Search Integers from Text File in Java

Tags: java

I have a sorted list of integers in a txt file (hosted publicly online), and I need to ask the user to give a number to search for in that list of integers via a binary search.

I'm in an intro to algorithms course and I am new to Java.

With the code I've got now I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 52, Size: 22
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at BinSearch4.main(BinSearch4.java:67)
```

*The while loop (listed below) is line 67

Can't seem to figure out what the problem is here. As well I am sure even some of the things I've got working could be implemented more efficiently. Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
/*  Binary Search Algorithm
 * 
 * - Import a sorted list of integers of an unknown length
 * 
 * - Ask the user for a number to search for (searchValue)
 * 
 * - Run a Binary Search on the list of integers without simply using binarySearch
 * 
 * - Return the index of an occurrence of the search number (searchValue)
 * 
 * - Or -1 if the target is not found.
 * 
 * 
 */


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BinSearch4 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL("http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3a/1423978916244.txt"); 
    ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    int searchValue;
    int low;
    int high;
    int mid;
    int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your number to search for:");
    searchValue = in.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println(searchValue);

    try {

        Scanner scr = new Scanner(url.openStream()); 

        while (scr.hasNextLine()) {
            int i = scr.nextInt();
            arrList.add(i);
        }
        scr.close();
        System.out.println(arrList);


    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    low = arrList.get(0);                      
    System.out.println(low);
    high = arrList.get(arrList.size() - 1);
    System.out.println(high);
    mid = (low + high) / 2;

    while (low <= high && arrList.get(mid) != searchValue) {
        if (arrList.get(mid) < searchValue) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else  {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
    }
    if (low > high) {
        mid = NOT_FOUND;
    }
    System.out.println(mid);

 }
}
```

The list of numbers in the text file are:
[-2, 3, 6, 9, 11, 22, 24, 31, 35, 43, 48, 52, 62, 65, 69, 70, 73, 83, 86, 90, 100, 107]

Comment: Please identify line # **67** in `BinSearch4.java` file.

Comment: The best way to solve this problem yourself and to learn to quickly solve similar problems in the future is to master the skill of debugging. There's 2 main skills here: 1) learn to add logging statements 2) learn to use a debugger tool. For 1, try printing to console the values of low, high, mid, arrList.get(low), arrList.get(high), arrList.get(mid) on every iteration. You'll see how your program behaves and you'll immediately see when exactly it went wrong. For 2, just use an IDE and step through your program, looking at the variables.

Comment: Any reason not to use Collections.binarySearch? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)

Comment: @Axel - this was for class exercise which required that we not use binarySearch. I think the point was for us to understand how the algorithm works. Its for an intro to algorithms course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary Search

```
public class BinarySearch {

    public int binarySearch(int[] a) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = a.length - 1;
        int searchedValue = 70;

        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
            int mid = (start + end) / 2;

            if (searchedValue == a[mid]) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (searchedValue < a[mid]) {
                end = mid - 1;
            } else {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = { 2, 5, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
        BinarySearch binarySearch = new BinarySearch();
        System.out.println(binarySearch.binarySearch(a));
    }
}
```

**start must be 0 and end will be arr.length-1**

Answer (score 0):

Change your lines from:

```
low = arrList.get(0);                      
System.out.println(low);
high = arrList.get(arrList.size() - 1);
```

To

```
low = 0;                      
System.out.println(low);
high = arrList.size() - 1;
```

Reason why you are getting exception is, if you have 10 elements in your list and say you have 100 - 110 as elements within the list, you are trying to access list element by index i.e. 100 which does not exists in your list as your list holds just 10 elements i.e. accessing elements beyond index 9 (as array index starts from 0 to n-1), you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both android_dev and almas here, they both were correct.

Here at this point in my original code posted here:

```
low = arrList.get(0);                      
System.out.println(low);
high = arrList.get(arrList.size() - 1);
```

I was referencing the value, I needed to reference the index. Hence the 'low' index would and will always need to be zero for a Binary Search program like this.

My correct code that now works is:

```
low = 0;                          
System.out.println(low);
high = arrList.size() - 1;
```